# Bash Cut diamond question mark symbol �

Tags: bash, cut

I am trying to display the 2nd and 7th character from each line of text.

```
while read line
do
  x=`echo $line | cut -c2,7`
  echo $x
done
```

Sample Input:

```
C.B - Cantonment Board/Cantonment    
C.M.C â€“ City Municipal Council    
C.T â€“ Census Town    
E.O â€“ Estate Office
```

Expected Output:

```
.C
.â
.“
.“
```

My output:

```
.C
.�
.�
.�
```

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Looks like you're splitting the codepoints into incomplete code units. I don't think `cut` is UTF-8-aware.

Answer (score 1):

`cut` does not really support Unicode. You might want to use Perl instead (adapted from [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163497/70524)):

```
perl -CIO -ne 'print substr($_, 1, 1) . substr($_, 6, 1) . "\n"'
```

For example:

```
$ perl -CIO -ne 'print substr($_, 1, 1) . substr($_, 6, 1) . "\n"' < foo
.C
.â
.“
.“
```

`-CIO` tells `perl` that both input and output are in Unicode. `substr(var, m, n)` extracts the substring of length `n` beginning at index `m` (starting from 0). So the second character is the substring of length 1 at index 1. `$_` is the variable holding the current input line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bash`'s substring parameter expansion.

```
while read line; do
    x=${line:1:1}${line:6:1}  # 0-based counting
    echo "$x"
done <<EOF
C.B - Cantonment Board/Cantonment
C.M.C â€“ City Municipal Council
C.T â€“ Census Town
E.O â€“ Estate Office
EOF
```

The form `${var:offset:length}` returns `length` characters starting at position `offset` in the value of `var`. Strings are 0-indexed, like arrays.

(I am not sure, though, if `bash` *always* handles utf-8 correctly, or if it depends on how it was compiled.)

Comment: I think it depends on the locale. With a UTF-8 locale, this works correctly, with the C locale, it behaves like `cut`.